# Invalid request to SOAP service does not produce expected SOAP fault

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, jboss, wildfly

I am calling a SOAP service running on WildFly (JBoss) which includes this operation:

```
<wsdl:operation name="checkIn">
  <wsdl:documentation>blah</wsdl:documentation>
  <wsdl:input message="tns:checkInRequestMsg" />
  <wsdl:output message="tns:checkInResponseMsg" />
  <wsdl:fault name="error" message="tns:errorMsg" />
</wsdl:operation>
```

When I call this service in Fiddler with an invalid request, I receive an HTTP 500 response that looks essentially like this (I have redacted slightly):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:tns="..." xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP:Body>
      <tns:error version="1.0">
         <reason>...</reason>
      </tns:error>
   </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

When I call this service with the same invalid request, using a .NET WCF service proxy generated by Visual Studio 2015, I am not getting a .NET exception and the response is null. I am unable to parse the error response.

The proxy defines the operation this way:

```
    // CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the operation checkIn is neither RPC nor document wrapped.
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="urn:checkIn", ReplyAction="*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(typeof(ConsoleApplication2.ServiceReference1.ServiceError), Action="urn:checkIn", Name="error")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    ConsoleApplication2.ServiceReference1.checkInResponse checkIn(ConsoleApplication2.ServiceReference1.checkInRequest request);
```

How can I call the service in .NET so that I can received parsed error responses instead of getting null responses? I would like to be able to use the .NET WCF generated proxy, and avoid having to parse the raw XML response!

Comment: If you are using the Add Service Reference, or svcutil.exe to generate you operation contracts and data contracts, its likely that wcf is renaming some of the elements as well as adding or expecting a wrapper tag. You may have to tweak the attributes on the code generated by .net.I would suggest adding diagnostic tracing for the messages so you can see what is being sent back and forth. Your repsonse may not be null, but is not being deserialized when handled by the client channel methods.

Answer (score 0):

I write my code as follows and could catch the customized exception.

MyServiceContract.

```
 [ServiceContract]
public  interface Test
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(CalculatorFault))]
    [XmlSerializerFormat(SupportFaults = true)]
    double add(double a, double b);
}
```

My exception model.

```
 [DataContract]
public class CalculatorFault
{
    [DataMember]
    public string OperationName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Fault { get; set; }
}
```

My service.

```
 public class ServiceTest : Test
{

    public double add(double a, double b)
    {

        if (b == 0)
        {
            throw new FaultException<CalculatorFault>(new CalculatorFault { OperationName = "divide", Fault = "hello" },"message");
        }
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

My client code.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ChannelFactory<Test> testf = new ChannelFactory<Test>("test"))
        {
         Test test =   testf.CreateChannel();
            try
            {
                test.add(0, 0);
            }
            catch (FaultException<CalculatorFault> ex)
            {


            }    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I don’t control the server side, it’s not .NET, and it doesn’t throw a proper SOAP fault although the WSDL says it should.